# Where is Gnome 12 in the Stranger Things game?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

Its the only thing I'm missing, and I'm going crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/StrangerThings/comments/74cbz5/stranger_things_the_game_discussion/)

> You can find it, in the Quarry, very bottom right corner of the map, past a bear that you distract with a pudding.